# Implement change password functionality in feathersjs project

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I am actually trying to implement change password functionality in my feathersjs project. what basically I am trying to do is, I am receiving input from user (old-password and new-password), first I have to compare the hash of this old-password with the hash of the password already stored in database, but when I generate the hash (using hashPassword() hook in feathers) of this old-password field provided by user and compare it with the password hash in database, I am getting negative response, even if I am using the same password (plain text of password).
The problem here is I am getting different hashes for the same string(because it is using salts internally) when I am using this hashPassword() function. So I am not able to compare the password hashes.
So, is there a function or something like that, that I can use to compare the string with hash or hash with hash.

```
>       async function checkPassword(context) { 
>       //already hashed. I also have the plain text of this string
>       const oldPassword = context.data.oldPassword; 
>       // const newPassword = context.data.newPassword;
>       //get the current logged-in users password(hash) from 
>       //database
>       const user = await app.service('users').get(context.id);
>       console.log('DB: ', user.password);
>     
>       if (oldPassword === user.password) {
>         //allowed to change password
>         return true;
>       
>     
>       } else {
>         //not allowed to change password
>         return false;
>       }
>     
>     }
```

Comment: If the hashes don't match eventhough the plaintext does, you are doing something wrong while hashing. Could be you have an error hashing the current user input, could be, you stored a wrong hash in the database.

Comment: actually the hashes are generated by the feathers itself, I am just passing the strings. I need to know  how to compare the password string with the password hash stored in the database. The problem here is, every time it is generating the different hash for the same string maybe because it is using salts internally. but the problem now arises how can we compare the passwords.